# Adobe Illustrator: Can't Fill Shapes with Color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, fill

I am new in Adobe Illustrator. I am facing an issue. I can't fill  a shape with color in Adobe Illustrator. But when I copy it in Paint app, I can easily do it. Here is the image of the shape:
[image]

I can't fill it with color by any mean. But when I copy it to Paint, I can do it. There, it looks like this:
[image]

How can I do the same thing Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: @Luciano I am new to this site. Would you please suggest me the correct way for rewording and reopening my question? Should I have to delete .ai files on Google Drive?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the shape in your AI file is not actually a closed shape, but separate paths, so you can't just change the fill attribute.

You can avoid this by using the Rounded Rectangle tool to make a closed path instead.

1. Select the Rounded Rectangle tool
2. Click once on the artboard
3. Input the settings shown below

[image]

4. Rotate the shape, and move into position, over the corner of the artboard
5. Select the shape and change the fill attribute (circled in red)

[image]

Comment: How can I remove the unwanted part effectively? I can use the eraser tool.But is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here's a half circle and two separate lines drawn at the ends of the circle. It surely will not get filled with Live paint nor Shape builder, because it's an open shape in the corner of the artboard.

A fix:

Draw a couple of extra lines or a rectangle to make a closed area:

[image]

Then select all and sweep with the shape builder tool over it from top left to bottom right. It get filled with the selected fill color:

[image]

A sweep with the Shape builder is needed, if the half circle has a fill. If it's not filled, then a single click inside the wanted new shape is enough

Ungroup the result and delete the unwanted remnants:

[image]